# How to write if statement for variable inside a stateless widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wondering is there any way to write an `if` statement inside a `StatelessWidget`. The target is I'm passing the `foodWeightVal`, a double value and `foodRoutine` string to my `FoodSchedule` class. Inside the `FoodSchedule` class, I want another variable `foodWeight` which will be a calculated value based on the value of `foodWeightVal` using an `if` statement.
My code is given below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FoodSchedule extends StatelessWidget {
  final double? foodWeightVal;
  final String? foodRoutine;

  FoodSchedule({@required this.foodWeightVal, @required this.foodRoutine});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (foodWeightVal == null) {
      var foodWeight = 0; // Error: The value of the local variable 'foodWeight' isn't used.
    } else {
      if (foodWeightVal! <= 300) {
        var foodWeight = foodWeight; // Error: Local variable 'foodWeight' can't be referenced before it is declared.
      } else {
        var foodWeight = 400 - foodWeightVal!;
      }
    }
    return Text('Take $foodWeight gm of food $foodRoutine'); // Error: Undefined name 'foodWeight'.
  }
}
```

The above code has several error as my approach is not correct. But what should I be doing here?

Comment: Hi there, are there any errors in the console that you post?

Comment: @JaffaKetchup Hi! I have updated the question with the errors as the comment.

Comment: It's nothing to do with being inside a stateless widget, or with anything framework-related at all. You simply need to declare `foodWeight` at a level above the `if` blocks — say, on the first line of the function — before you try to access it within the the blocks. That's how it works in most (though not all) popular languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you made 3 different foodWeight variables that are only accessable inside of their if clauses.

## Correct Code

```dart
class FoodSchedule extends StatelessWidget {
  final double? foodWeightVal;
  final String? foodRoutine;

  FoodSchedule({@required this.foodWeightVal, @required this.foodRoutine});
  
double foodWeight = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (foodWeightVal == null) {
      foodWeight = 0; 
    } else {
      if (foodWeightVal! <= 300) {
        foodWeight = foodWeight; // I dont understand what you want to do here actually
      } else {
        foodWeight = 400 - foodWeightVal!;
      }
    }
    return Text('Take $foodWeight gm of food $foodRoutine');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define `foodWeight` before the if statements. I'd do this:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double foodWeight = 0;
    if (foodWeightVal == null) foodWeight = 0.0; 
    else if (foodWeightVal! <= 300) {
        // Not entirely sure what you mean here.
    } else {
        foodWeight = 400.0 - foodWeightVal!;
    }
    
    return Text('Take $foodWeight gm of food $foodRoutine');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `The value of the local variable 'foodWeight' isn't used.` is just a warning, not an error as the variable `foodWeight` isn't referenced anywhere after it's been assigned which makes no sense.

Secondly, `var foodWeight = foodWeight;` what kind of mistake is this? I mean you're trying to assign a value from a variable that isn't declared yet, which doesn't exist even!!

and lastly, you're trying to use the value of the variable `foodWeight` which isn't defined in the scope.